# List of vocabulary (kanjis) for the JLPT1 exam

Tags: data-request, language, education, japanese

I am preparing for the [Japanese Language Proficiency Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese-Language_Proficiency_Test) N1.

I am looking for a list of vocabulary (kanjis) that I should probably study for this test.

I know there is no official list, but is there a good free list?

I have already tried but am not satisfied with:

- The shared decks at Ankiweb, they are not exhaustive.
- The TANOS data, it contains error and dialect.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [AJet](http://ajet.net/ajetdownloads/jlpt-resources/) resources (Japanese Language Proficiency Test Resources)?